# Making the output of an operation to display 2 decimal points

Tags: java

Here's my current code:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Addition
{
    // main method begins execution of Java application
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       // create Scanner to obtain input from command window
       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );            

       int area;
       int number1;
       int number2;


       System.out.print( "Input base value =  " ); // prompt
       number1 = input.nextInt(); // read first number from user

       System.out.print( "Input height value = " ); // prompt
       number2 = input.nextInt(); // read second number from user

       area = 1/2*(number1*number2); // add numbers
       System.out.printf( "The Area of the right triangle is %d\n", area ); // display sum

    } // end method main

 } // end class Addition
```

I would like to make it display the decimal point when i input 5 as the first and second number. i tried replacing **int area** with **double area** but doesn't work..

Comment: 2 digits after it.. like if i input 5 for both values the output would be 12.50

Answer (score 1):

If you want two digits after the decimal point, you must make `area` a double and use a format string of `%1.2f`.

Example:

```
System.out.printf("%1.2f\n", 78785.7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the vast array of examples here:

[Formatting Numerical Data](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/FormattingNumericalData.htm)

Hope it helps :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making area a double, you'll also need to make at least one of the terms in `1/2*(number1*number2)` a double, or you'll only be doing int math, which won't turn out how you expect. For example:

```
1.0/2*(number1*number2)
```

In your output, you'll also have to use %f instead of %d.